# Spy on static methods of Service class Angular2 Jasmine Typescript

Tags: jasmine, angular2-services

I am facing problem where I have created an `Injectable` service class having static methods like:

```
declare let Granite: any;

@Injectable()
export class I18NService {

    public static get(key:string):string {
        return Granite.I18n.get(key);
    }

}
```

and I am trying to test it using jasmine where I have written my test cases like:

```
export function main() {

    fdescribe('Granite Service', () => {
        class MockGraniteService {
            get(st: string): string {
                return '';
            }
        }
        beforeEach(() => {
            //spyOn(I18NService, 'get').and.callThrough();
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                providers: [{
                    provide: I18NService,
                    useClass: MockGraniteService
                }]
            });
        });


        it('should be granite processed value from Granite API', () => {
            //Spy
            spyOn(I18NService, 'get').and.callFake(() => {
                return "Ship To";
            });
            let processedVal = I18NService.get('mkt.header.shipToLabel');
            expect(processedVal).toBeTruthy();
            expect(processedVal).toEqual('Ship To');
        });

    })

}
```

when I am spying on `get()` it is excluded from code coverage and when i directly call the function using `callThrough()`, it is making an actual call but not getting granite processed value. Any help?